# Urban Airship + Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, components, urbanairship.com

I am trying to implement Urban Airship in our Xamarin application that uses Mvvmx. I installed the component through the Component store. We only needed to add three things:

- UAirship.takeoff()
- AirshipConfig.plist file
- UAirship.Push.UserPushNotificationsEnabled = true;

I am getting a object reference null pointer when calling

```
 UAirship.Push.UserPushNotificationsEnabled = true;
```

Has anyone been successful at implementing Urban Airship in Xamarin.iOS?

We have an account with UA for our native iOS applications and would love to continue to use them for our Xamarin apps.

Answer (score 0):

When are you calling `UAirship.Push.UserNotificaiontsEnabled`? It must be called after takeOff.

Comment: I have it called right after `UAirship.takeOff();`in the AppDelegate didFinishLaunching:

Comment: Check the logs. If your airship config is invalid takeoff will abort early if the airship config is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having this issue.  I have added the AirshipConfig.plist and set the values, but is there some way that the app needs to reference the plist that I am unaware of?  The documentation just says to provide the AirshipConfig.plist.